# How would you make abstracted nested dictionary/hashtable objects readable (style)?

Tags: powershell, powershell-5.0

I'm parsing a database table exported into csv where there are embedded fields in what is essentially a memo field.
The database also contains version history, and the csv contains all versions.
Basic structure of the data is Index(sequential record number),Reference(specific foreign key), Sequence (order of records for a given reference), and Data (the memo field with the data to parse).

You could think of the "Data" field as text documents limited to 80 chars wide and 40 chars deep, and then sequenced in the order they would print. Every record entry is assigned an ascending index.
For reference, $myParser is a [Microsoft.VisualBasic.FileIO.TextFieldParser], so ReadFields() returns a row of fields as an array/list.

My ultimate question is, how can this be formatted to be more intuitive to the reader? Below code is powershell, i'd be interested in answers relating to C# also,as it's something of a language agnostic style problem, though i think get/set would trivialize this to some degree.

Consider the following code (an insert/update routine in a 2 deep nested dictionary/hash):

```
enum cmtField
{
    Index = 0
    Sequence = 1
    Reference = 2
    Data = 4
}

$myRecords = [System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[int,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[int,string]]]::new() #this could be a hash table, but is more verbose this way
While($true) #there's actually control here, but this provides a simple loop assuming infinite data
{
    $myFields = $myParser.ReadFields() #read a line from the csvfile and return an array/list of fields for that line

    if(!$myRecords.ContainsKey($myFields[[cmtField]::Reference])) #if the reference of the current record is new
    {
        $myRecords.Add($myFields[[cmtField]::Reference],[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[int,CommentRecord]]::new()) #create tier 1 reference index
        $myRecords[$myFields[[cmtField]::Reference]].add($myFields[[cmtField]::Sequence],$myFields[[cmtField]::Data]) #create tier 2 sequence reference and data
    }
    else #if the reference aklready exists in the dictionary
    {
        if(!$myRecords[$myFields[[cmtField]::Reference]].ContainsKey($myFields[[cmtField]::Sequence])) #if the sequence ID of the current record is new
        {
            $myRecords[$myFields[[cmtField]::Reference]].Add($myFields[[cmtField]::Sequence],$myFields[[cmtField]::Data]) #add record at [reference][sequence]
        }
        else #if the sequence already exists for this reference
        {
            if($myRecords[$myFields[[cmtField]::Reference]][$myFields[[cmtField]::Sequence]].Index -lt $myFields[[cmtField]::Index]) #if the index of the currently read field is higher than the store index, it must be newer
            {
                $myRecords[$myFields[[cmtField]::Reference]][$myFields[[cmtField]::Sequence]] = $myFields[[cmtField]::Data] #replace with new data
            }
            #else discard currently read data (do nothing
        }
    }
}
```

Frankly, trying to make this readable both makes my head hurt and my eyes bleed a little. It only gets messier and messier the deeper the dictionary goes. I'm stuck between the bracket soup and no self-documentation.

Comment: You want only better-view  of code? I'd start to replacing `$myFields[[cmtField]::Reference]` with `$MyFields.Reference` or just `$Reference` in your code. This can be done by simple wrapping around `$myParser.ReadFields()` I think

Comment: @filimonic Can you expound a little on what you mean by "simple wrapping around $myParser.ReadFields()"?

Comment: `$myRecords[$myFields[[cmtField]::Reference]]` => `$myRecords[$myFields.Reference]`. Like this : `$myFields2 = [PSCustomObject]@{ Reference =  $myFields[[cmtField]::Reference]; Sequence = $myFields[[cmtField]::Sequence]}`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> My ultimate question is, how can this be formatted to be more intuitive to the reader?

That... ultimately depends on who "the reader" is - is it your boss? Your colleagues? Me? Will you use this code sample to teach programming to someone?

In terms of making it less "messy", there are a couple of immediate steps you can take.

The first thing I would change to make your code more readable, would be to add a `using namespace` directive at the top of the file:

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic
```

Now you can create nested dictionaries with:

```
[Dictionary[int,Dictionary[int,string]]]::new()
```

... as opposed to:

```
[System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[int,System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary[int,string]]]::new()
```

The next thing I would reduce is repeated index access patterns like `$myFields[[cmtField]::Reference]` - you never modify `$myFields` after initial assignment at the top of the loop, so there's no need to delay resolution of it.

```
while($true)
{
    $myFields = $myParser.ReadFields()

    $Reference = $myFields[[cmtField]::Reference]
    $Data      = $myFields[[cmtField]::Data]
    $Sequence  = $myFields[[cmtField]::Sequence]
    $Index     = $myFields[[cmtField]::Index]

    if(!$myRecords.ContainsKey($Reference)) #if the reference of the current record is new
    {
        $myRecords.Add($Reference,[Dictionary[int,CommentRecord]]::new()) #create tier 1 reference index
        $myRecords[$Reference].Add($Sequence,$Data) #create tier 2 sequence reference and data
    }
    else 
    {
        # ...
```

Finally, you can simplify the code vastly by abandoning nested if/else statements, and instead just break it down into a succession of steps that has to pass one by one, and you end up with something like this:

```
using namespace System.Collections.Generic

enum cmtField
{
    Index = 0
    Sequence = 1
    Reference = 2
    Data = 4
}

$myRecords = [Dictionary[int,Dictionary[int,CommentRecord]]]::new() 
while($true) 
{
    $myFields = $myParser.ReadFields()

    $Reference = $myFields[[cmtField]::Reference]
    $Data = $myFields[[cmtField]::Data]
    $Sequence = $myFields[[cmtField]::Sequence]
    $Index = $myFields[[cmtField]::Index]

    # Step 1 - ensure tier 1 dictionary is present
    if(!$myRecords.ContainsKey($Reference))
    {
        $myRecords.Add($Reference,[Dictionary[int,CommentRecord]]::new())
    }
    
    # (now we only need to resolve `$myRecords[$Reference]` once)
    $record = $myRecords[$Reference]

    # step 2 - ensure sequence entry exists
    if(!$record.ContainsKey($Sequence))
    {
        $record.Add($Sequence, $Data)
    }

    # step 3 - handle superceding comment records
    if($record[$Sequence].Index -lt $Index) 
    {
        $record[$Sequence] = $Data 
    }
}
```

I personally find this easier on the eyes (and mind) than the original if/else approach

Comment: I like the result, and i imagine the boiler response is going to be "it's irrelevant" but mostly i didn't originally re-reference the fields to variables as i would expect, being primitives, those will consume more memory  as a copy-by-value operation. Of course, without running some benchmarks, i don't know if ultimately the memory copies are faster than the constant hash/dictionary dereferencing/index lookup. Though, i suspect the dictionary would ultimately be slower, right?

Comment: @ChristopherEberle keep in mind that there's a very thin line between "compile-time" and "runtime" in PowerShell, so the patterns you've adopted for a language like C# might not always be relevant (as you point out), and in some cases even _counter-intuitive_ (_because_ there's no "compile-time optimizations" to be had). In this particular case, index access _is_ faster in PowerShell, but the difference is so negligible it won't matter until you reach an input size where you'd probably re-evaluate whether PowerShell is the best tool for the job anyway :-)

Comment: It definitely should be done in something other than powershell, but i'm required to guarantee ubiquitous source code access for posterity in an environment where visual studio and source control are not yet well deployed. The solution for this will involve a few different data processing operations which handle some ~1M records. Powershell is definitely not the optimal way to accomplish this.

Comment: @ChristopherEberle I hear ya, enterprise IT is never the promised land ^_^ My immediate advice is: strive for correctness and readability, optimize later

Comment: Not a lot of traffic, which i'll take as consensus (or a lack of interest, in either case, it's been a while). Thanks for your input, Mathias! With minor changes, this is the approach i've taken.